# Is this induced mapping continuous?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y,Z$ be topological spaces, and let $f:X\to Y$ and $g:X\to Z$ be continuous functions.

Suppose that $f$ is constant on each fiber of $g$, i.e. for every $z\in Z$, the fiber $g^{-1}(z) \subseteq X$ is sent to a single point $y_z\in Y$. Then clearly there exists a mapping $Z \to Y$ sending $z$ to $y_z$.

Is this mapping continuous?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does not have to be.

Consider $X=Y=Z$ as sets and $f(x)=g(x)=x$. Then the induced function $Z\to Y$ is the identity as well. Now put discrete topology on $X$ and $Y$ and a non-discrete on $Z$.